# Can someone please tell me why it is 4?

Tags: java

Consider the following method:

```
public int foo(int n) {
    int x = 1;
    int k = 0;
    while (x <= n) {
        x = x * 2;
        k = k + 1;
    }
    return k;
}
```

What value is returned by `foo(13)`? I know the answer is 4 but could someone please tell me why it is 4?

Comment: Is there something else you think it should be? Have you tried simply going through the sequence of steps the program would perform?

Comment: Really??? I mean by the time you wrote the question you could have done the calculation using your fingers..

Comment: It's funny how much attention this question is attracting.

Answer (score 3):

`x` doubles with every iteration through the loop, and `k` increases by 1 every time through.

It's simple enough to draw out with a table.

```
x  |  k 
1  |  0  
2  |  1
4  |  2
8  |  3
16 |  4
32 | <end of loop>
```

Answer (score 1):

`x` doubles at each step until it becomes greater than `13`. So `x = 1 -> 2 -> 4 -> 8 -> 16`. So it gets doubled 4 times and `k` is also incremented `4` times. So from `0` it becomes `4`.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the step/algorithm steps:

```
X=1 k=0 n =13

Step 1: x=2 k=1 

Step 2: x=4 k=2

Step 3: x=8 k = 3. Since 8<13...

Step 4: x=16 k= 4. 16>13, so return k=4.
```

Answer (score 0):

Its finding n < 2^k where k is your answer. When n = 13: 13 < 2^k = 2^4 = 16.

Answer (score 0):

K is the number of times the while loop is entered.

As x is 2 power, 2^3 is little than 13, so it enters one last time, 2^4 is bigger than 13, and then k is 4

Answer (score 0):

pretty simple...

```
public int foo([13]) {
    int x = 1;
    int k = 0;
    while (x <= n) {
        x = x * 2;
        k = k + 1;
    }
    return k;
}
```

your while loop stops when x is bigger or equal to n[13]

each time x is multiplied by 2

(definition)x = 1

1. x =    2
2. x =    4
3. x =    8
4. x =    16 (is now over n[13])

and so the while loop runs 4 times

```
while (x <= n) {
            x = x * 2;
            k = k + 1;//dis thang
        }
```

k[0]+1=1

k[1]+1=2

k[2]+1=3

k[3]+1=4

and thats why its 4.